# How to convert String into Date object using "DateFormat"?

Tags: java, datetime, java.util.date

I am trying to convert the date/Time of my machine into GMT time zone by using the following code:

```
DateFormat gmtFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss 'GMT' yyyy");
TimeZone gmtTime = TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT");
gmtFormat.setTimeZone(gmtTime);
System.out.println("Orginal Date : " + new Date());
String s= gmtFormat.format(new Date());
System.out.println("Converted Date As String: "+ s);
System.out.println("Converted Date As date object : " + gmtFormat.parse(s));
```

Above code output :

```
Orginal Date : Mon Apr 21 21:04:06 AST 2014
Converted Date As String: Mon Apr 21 18:04:06 GMT 2014
Converted Date As date object : Mon Apr 21 21:04:06 AST 2014
```

However my problem when I parse the " Converted Date As String " to " Converted Date As date object " by using the parse function, but as you can notice that the date changes to the original date

Why is that happen ?

---

The problem is solve, when I do the following :

```
DateFormat gmtFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss 'GMT' yyyy");
TimeZone gmtTime = TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT");
gmtFormat.setTimeZone(gmtTime);
System.out.println("Orginal Date : " + new Date());
String s= gmtFormat.format(new Date());
System.out.println("Converted Date As String: "+ s);
// Just I added Local Time Zone Formatand I use it to call parse instead of gmtFormat
DateFormat LocalFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss 'GMT' yyyy");
System.out.println("Converted Date As date object : " + LocalFormat.parse(s));
```

I am wondering why thats happen >> How the Local format related to parse Function ? Does any one know why?

Answer (score 1):

The return value from `DateFormat.parse(String)` is a `java.util.Date`, which does not retain any information about time zone or locale. A `Date` is essentially a wrapper object around a `long` value representing a number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970 at 00:00 GMT. When its `toString()` method is invoked, the default implementation renders the date in your local system's default timezone.

If you want to create a date/time representation which stores both a timestamp **and** an associated time zone / locale, you should create a `java.util.Calendar` object (using `Calendar.getInstance(...)` and provide it with a `TimeZone` and/or a `Locale`, then set the time associated with the calendar with the `Date` object representing the date/time you want.

Comment: I tried the following code with calender but I get my local machine time even though I set the timeZone to GMT :                          SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
Calendar cal =Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+00:00"));
System.out.println(f.format(cal.getTime()));
System.out.println(f.parse(f.format(cal.getTime())));

Comment: You'll also need to keep this line from your original code, where you set the time zone on the formatter: `gmtFormat.setTimeZone(gmtTime);`. Keep in mind that whenever you call `Calendar.getTime()` or `DateFormat.parse()`, the return value is still a `Date`, so even if the object which produced it is time-zone-aware, the `Date` itself is just a long value (which will need to be given a time zone).

Comment: Sorry for annoying you, but what do you mean by "the Date itself is just a long value (which will need to be given a time zone)"